# rvm install 1.8.7 error

Tags: ruby, gcc, rvm

I'm trying to install ruby 1.8.7

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/12.04/x86_64/ruby-1.8.7-p371.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing Ruby from source to: ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.8.7-p371 - #downloading ruby-1.8.7-p371, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.8.7-p371 - #extracted to ~/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p371 (already extracted)
Patch stdout-rouge-fix was already applied.
Patch no_sslv2 was already applied.
ruby-1.8.7-p371 - #configuring
ruby-1.8.7-p371 - #compiling
Error running 'make', please read ~/.rvm/log/ruby-1.8.7-p371/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
Please be aware that you just installed a ruby that requires 2 patches just to be compiled on up to date linux system.
This may have known and unaccounted for security vulnerabilities.
Please consider upgrading to ruby-1.9.3-p385 which will have all of the latest security patches.
```

cat ~/.rvm/log/ruby-1.8.7-p371/make.log

```
gcc -g -O2  -fPIC    -DRUBY_EXPORT -D_GNU_SOURCE=1  -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic   main.o  libruby-static.a -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -o miniruby
./lib/fileutils.rb:1410:  is not a class/module (TypeError)
        from ./mkconfig.rb:11:in `require'
        from ./mkconfig.rb:11
make: *** [.rbconfig.time] Error 1
```

gcc -v

```
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/lto-wrapper
: x86_64-linux-gnu
: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
: posix
gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
```

rvm 1.18.6 (stable)

Have any ideas?

Comment: Ubuntu/Linaro .. does that mean you're targeting an ARM processor?  You could try installing from source and seeing if `configure` prints any warnings.  Can you compile any version of ruby?  What about 1.9.3-p385?

Comment: I use x86_64 system. ruby-1.9.3-p385 has already been successfully installed, but i want install ruby-1.8.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just installed a new version (1.20.5) of the RVM and I was able to put the ruby version 1.8.7

I install rvm -v from ubuntu repos

```
rvm 1.6.9
```

and try again

```
rvm install 1.8.7-p371
```

and it worked for me

```
Install of ruby-1.8.7-p371 - #complete
```

Comment: Yes, i downgraded to rvm 1.6. I tried to put rvm v 1.8.0, but could not find how to do it

Comment: I just installed a new version (1.20.5) of the RVM and I was able to put the ruby version 1.8.7 and 2.0.0 simultaneously. All my problems were resolved. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
rvm remove 1.8.7
rvm install 1.8.7
```

please take a note that `ruby-1.8.7` is **End Of Life** - there will be nno updates either for bugs or security issues, you need to consider updating to ruby `1.9.2` / `1.9.3` / `2.0.0`, my vote is `2.0.0` which will be released in few days