# how to install two versions of the RVM

Tags: ruby, linux, rvm

I use a very old ruby 1.8.7 which is installed only very old RVM 1.6.9, and I would like to install a new Ruby but my RVM only knows about Ruby 1.9.2 version. I would like to put a new version of the RVM kept the old one, but there is a conflict. Please tell me how to put a new version of Ruby without deleting the old one?

p.s. I installed rvm from ubuntu repositories

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just have the new RVM version install both 1.8.7 and the 2.0 you want? I thought the whole point of RVM was to only have *one* "fake" Ruby that directs to implementations. If you're using bundler then you should only need the RVM installations to be "clean".

Comment: millimoose, i install old rvm version because it's the only way out of my previous problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14887999/rvm-install-1-8-7-error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you simply update your rvm? You can do this by

```
rvm update --head
```

or

```
rvm get head --auto
```

According to your RVM version.

Answer (score 3):

You are using old and broken (by Ubuntu) package of RVM, please use this instructions to update https://stackoverflow.com/a/9056395/497756

Comment: it's the only way out of my previous problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14887999/rvm-install-1-8-7-error

Comment: the version in ubuntu repositories is very old, there was number of bug fixed in RVM since version `1.6.9` - the current version is `1.20.5` it's two years of hard work to fix bugs and implement new features like `autolibs`, if you can get the old version working - it's all fine, but first time it breaks just update it because nobody will debug version two years old that is no more supported.

Comment: I just installed a new version of the RVM and I was able to put the ruby version 1.8.7 and 2.0.0 simultaneously. Now I do not want to put two versions of the RVM simultaneously, all my problems were resolved. Thank you.